# Merge values when finding duplicate value in range

Tags: vba, excel, loops, merge

**My workbook:**

I have a workbook, and within it, I have three different sheets. Sheet 1 is some data from a PDF-file, where I use TextToColumns to align in cells. Sheet 2 contains data from our financial database, whereas it is already split into cells. Sheet 3 compares the two sets of data, from Sheet 1 and Sheet 2.

**My issue:**

The data from Sheet 1 has the same invoice and creditmemo numbers as the data from Sheet 2, but the appendix number for the payment doesn't add up, since it's two different companies. However the appendix number from Sheet 2 has something like "5786" and the appendix number from Sheet 1 is blank.

Other than that, the appendix number from Sheet 2 is split up in a payment and a discount.

I haven't started on making the code, since I don't know how to make it loop through for duplicates.

**My code:**

```
    Sub CopyPasteDataLookingForHeader()
    Dim sht, sht2, sht3 As Worksheet
    Dim i, LastRow, LastRow1, LastRow2, LastRow3, LastRow4, LastRow5 As Long
    Dim FindNo, Number, NumberOne, FindAmount, Amount, AmountOne As String
    Dim FindNo2, Number2, NumberTwo, FindAmount2, Amount2, AmountTwo As String
    Dim FindDate, Dato, DateOne, FindDate2, Dato2, DateTwo As String
    Set sht = Sheets("Kvik kontoudtog")
    Set sht2 = Sheets("Navision kontoudtog")
    Set sht3 = Sheets("Afstemning")
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim i21, LastRow21, LastRowDateSub As Long
    Dim FindDate21, DateSub, FindDateOffset, FindDescrip, DescripSub, FindDescripOffset As String
    Dim rng9, rng10, rng11, c, celle, Rw As Range

    'CONVERT INTO TEXT TO COLUMNS AND ALIGN COLUMNS

    sht.Activate

    'DELETE UNWANTED ROWS' TEXT

    FindDate21 = sht.Range("1:1").Find("Bogføringsdato", Lookat:=xlWhole).Address(False, False, xlA1)
    DateSub = sht.Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(FindDate21, 1, "")
    FindDateOffset = sht.Range(FindDate21).Offset(1, 0).Address(False, False, xlA1)
    LastRowDateSub = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, DateSub).End(xlUp).Row

    rng1 = FindDateOffset & ":" & DateSub & LastRowDateSub

    Set rng10 = Range(rng1)

        For Each c In rng10.Cells
            If TypeName(c.Value) <> "Date" Then
            c.EntireRow.ClearContents
            End If
        Next c

    'INSERT CELLS NEXT TO "Kontantrabat" AND "Rente"

    FindDescrip = sht.Range("1:1").Find("Beskrivelse", Lookat:=xlWhole).Address(False, False, xlA1)
    DescripSub = sht.Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(FindDescrip, 1, "")
    LastRow21 = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, DescripSub).End(xlUp).Row
    DescripSub2 = sht.Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(FindDescrip, 1, LastRow21)
    FindDescripOffset = sht.Range(FindDescrip).Offset(1, 0).Address(False, False, xlA1)

    Set rng9 = Range(FindDescripOffset, DescripSub2)

        For Each c In rng9.Cells
            If c = "Kontantrabat" Then
            c.Offset(0, 1).Insert Shift:=xlShiftToRight
            End If
        Next c

        For Each c In rng9.Cells
            If c = "Rente" Then
            CValue = c.Address(False, False, xlA1)
            CValueOffset = Range(CValue).Offset(0, 1).Address(False, False, xlA1)
            sht.Range(CValue).Value = Range(CValue).Value & " " & Range(CValueOffset).Value
            sht.Range(CValueOffset).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
            End If
        Next c
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    'CONTINUE TO DELETE THE UNWANTED ROWS

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    rng10.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    FindSaldo = sht.Range("1:1").Find("Saldo", Lookat:=xlWhole).Address(False, False, xlA1)
    SaldoSub = sht.Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(FindSaldo, 1, "")
    FindSaldoOffset = sht.Range(FindSaldo).Offset(1, 0).Address(False, False, xlA1)
    LastRowSaldoSub = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, SaldoSub).End(xlUp).Row

    rng12 = FindSaldoOffset & ":" & SaldoSub & LastRowSaldoSub
    Set rng11 = Range(rng12)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    rng11.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    'CENTER TEXT IN "Bilagsnr."

    FindBilagsnr = sht.Range("1:1").Find("Bilagsnr.", Lookat:=xlWhole).Address(False, False, xlA1)
    BilagsnrSub = sht.Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(FindBilagsnr, 1, "")
    LastRow2 = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, BilagsnrSub).End(xlUp).Row
    BilagsnrOffset = Range(FindBilagsnr).Offset(1, 0).Address(False, False, xlA1)

    rng3 = BilagsnrOffset & ":" & BilagsnrSub & LastRow2

    sht.Range(rng3).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    'ALIGN ROWS IN "NAVISION KONTOUDTOG"

    sht2.Activate

    FindNo1 = sht2.Range("1:1").Find("Eksternt bilagsnr.").Address(False, False, xlA1)
    Number1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(FindNo1, 1, "")
    LastRowNumber1 = sht2.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, Number1).End(xlUp).Row

    rng1171 = FindNo1 & ":" & Number1 & LastRowNumber1
    Set rng15 = Range(rng1171)

        For Each celle In rng15.Cells
            If celle = "10000" Then
            celle.Insert Shift:=xlShiftToRight
            End If
        Next celle
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    'CENTER TEXT IN "Eksternt bilagsnr."

    FindEBilagsnr = sht2.Range("1:1").Find("Eksternt bilagsnr.").Address(False, False, xlA1)
    EBilagsnrSub = sht2.Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(FindEBilagsnr, 1, "")
    LastRow2E = sht2.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, EBilagsnrSub).End(xlUp).Row
    EBilagsnrOffset = Range(FindEBilagsnr).Offset(1, 0).Address(False, False, xlA1)

    rng4 = EBilagsnrOffset & ":" & EBilagsnrSub & LastRow2E

    sht2.Range(rng4).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    'INSERT CELLS FOR ENTIRE COLUMN "VALUTAKODE"

    FindValuta = sht2.Range("1:1").Find("Valutakode").Address(False, False, xlA1)
    ValutaSub = sht2.Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(FindValuta, 1, "")
    LastRowValuta = sht2.Cells(sht2.Rows.Count, ValutaSub).End(xlUp).Row
    ValutaOffset = sht2.Range(FindValuta).Offset(1, 0).Address(False, False, xlA1)

    rng111 = ValutaOffset & ":" & ValutaSub & LastRowValuta
    Range(rng111).Insert Shift:=xlShiftToRight
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    'COMPARING PROCESS

    FindNo = sht.Range("1:1").Find("Bilagsnr.").Address(False, False, xlA1)
    Number = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(FindNo, 1, "")
    NumberOne = FindNo

    FindNo2 = sht2.Range("1:1").Find("Eksternt bilagsnr.").Address(False, False, xlA1)
    Number2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(FindNo2, 1, "")
    NumberTwo = FindNo2

    FindAmount = sht.Range("1:1").Find("Oprindeligt beløb").Address(False, False, xlA1)
    Amount = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(FindAmount, 1, "")
    AmountOne = FindAmount

    FindAmount2 = sht2.Range("1:1").Find("Beløb").Address(False, False, xlA1)
    Amount2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(FindAmount2, 1, "")
    AmountTwo = FindAmount2

    FindDate = sht.Range("1:1").Find("Bogføringsdato").Address(False, False, xlA1)
    Dato = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(FindDate, 1, "")
    DateOne = FindDate

    FindDate2 = sht.Range("1:1").Find("Bogføringsdato").Address(False, False, xlA1)
    Dato2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(FindDate2, 1, "")
    DateTwo = FindDate2

    LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, Number).End(xlUp).Address(False, False, xlA1)
    LastRow1 = sht2.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, Number2).End(xlUp).Address(False, False, xlA1)

    LastRowAmount = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(LastRow, Number, Amount)
    LastRowAmount2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(LastRow1, Number2, Amount2)
    LastRowDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(LastRow, Number, Dato)
    LastRowDate2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(LastRow1, Number2, Dato2)



    rng1 = NumberOne & ":" & LastRow
    rng2 = AmountOne & ":" & LastRowAmount
    rng3 = NumberTwo & ":" & LastRow1
    rng4 = AmountTwo & ":" & LastRowAmount2
    rng5 = DateOne & ":" & LastRowDate
    rng6 = DateTwo & ":" & LastRowDate2

    '------------------------------------------
    sht.Range(rng5).Copy
    sht3.Activate
    Range("F2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    '------------------------------------------
    sht.Range(rng1).Copy
    sht3.Activate
    Range("G2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    '------------------------------------------
    sht.Range(rng2).Copy
    sht3.Activate
    Range("H2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    '------------------------------------------
    sht2.Range(rng6).Copy
    sht3.Activate
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    '------------------------------------------
    sht2.Range(rng3).Copy
    sht3.Activate
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    '------------------------------------------
    sht2.Range(rng4).Copy
    sht3.Activate
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    '------------------------------------------

    Columns("A:H").ColumnWidth = 25

    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'PUT IN VLOOKUP

    sht3.Range(FindAmount).Offset(1, 1).Value = "VLOOKUP"

    FindVLOOKUP = sht3.Range("2:2").Find("VLOOKUP").Address(False, False, xlA1)
    VLOOKUP1 = sht3.Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(FindVLOOKUP, 2, "")

    FindVLOOKUPOffset = sht3.Range(FindVLOOKUP).Offset(1, 0).Address(False, False, xlA1)

    sht3.Range(FindVLOOKUPOffset).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G3,$B$3:$C$10000,2,False),0)+H3"

    'FILL VLOOKUP TO LASTROW
    FindAmount3 = sht3.Range("1:1").Find("Kvik kontoudtog").Address(False, False, xlWhole)
    Amount3 = sht3.Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(FindAmount3, 1, "")
    LastRowVLOOK = sht3.Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(LastRow, Number, Amount3)
    LastRowVLOOKUP = sht3.Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(LastRowVLOOK, Amount3, VLOOKUP1)

    sht3.Range(FindVLOOKUP).Offset(1, 0).Copy
    sht3.Range(FindVLOOKUPOffset, LastRowVLOOKUP).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End Sub
```

**Goal:**

Is there by any chance that I can merge the two appendix numbers into one, and SUM up the amount, just as if I made a pivot-table.

*Bonus goal:*
Then afterwards have the code loop through the data from Sheet 1, and .Find the blank cells. Whenever it finds a blank cell, it should compare the amount, with the data from Sheet 2, and if it finds a match (with opposite algebraic sign), it should take the appendix number from the matched amount, and insert it into the blank cell. Then loop through to find the next blank cell?

**Sample of Data**

I have uploaded the sample file to:

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsQuasddi71ugRqHjco1z_ZEqKnC

Comment: Please include the code you are working with in your question.

Comment: I have now inserted the code... It is very long...  In the bottom I want the to add the new strings, so that it wont "pop" out with my VLOOKUP, as if it has an insane difference.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain more about your appendix numbers which "don't add up in payment", "have something like 5786" or might be blank, and can be "split between payment and discount". Most of us haven't met such appendices before.

Comment: You have already found the need to split your code into sections for which you have inserted captions. The better way to achieve this result is to write separate sub procedures for each caption which you call from a `Main` procedure. There would be only 15 or 20 lines of code in each subs and perhaps a similar number in the main. You will find it much easier to test your code, faster to write it and easier to ask questions, too. Hopefully, it would also be easier for me to understand how I might help you.

Comment: Could you post a sample of what the data looks like now, as well as an example of what you are trying to *make it* look like?  Also, check out [mcve].

Comment: The thing about the appendix number is that Sheet 1 is my company's data, and Sheet 2 the other company's data. All the data, which I am looking for in Sheet 3, is linked by date, appendix number from the other company, and the amount. Since I don't know what the external appendix number is, all payment's will be left as blanks in my system.